# Add Values to Field JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of Checkboxes on a page which I am getting hold of using JQuery, on a user clicking the checkbox I need the value to be sent to a field which will be hidden and I need each value added to be delimited by a | I have written the following.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="_CKBXprod_link"]').attr("id", "_CKBXprod_link");
           $('input[name="_CKBXprod_link"]').click(function() {
               $('#link_ids').val(this.value+"|");
           });
        });
```

Simple! ;) can anyone tell me what I am missing it is adding values but they are replace by each click of a checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

I think what you really want is a input box that holds all your checked
checkboxes uniquely.

#### Sample

```
<input type="text" id="link_ids"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="_CKBXprod_link" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="_CKBXprod_link" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="_CKBXprod_link" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="_CKBXprod_link" value="4"/>

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('._CKBXprod_link').click(function() {
        var checkboxes = $("._CKBXprod_link:checked");
        var values = "";
        checkboxes .each(function() {
           values += $(this).val() + "|";
        });

        $(link_ids).val(values.substring(0, values.length-1));
    });
});
```

## Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qRnfq/2/)

Comment: Just a quick question @dknaack is there away to achieve the same using the input[name="_CKBprod_link"] syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.
You are setting the current value only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[name="_CKBXprod_link"]').attr("id", "_CKBXprod_link");
               $('input[name="_CKBXprod_link"]').click(function() {
                   var strVal = $('#link_ids').val();
                   $('#link_ids').val(strVal + "|"+this.value);
               });
            });
```

Comment: This is great thanks, as an extra could you show in this code how you would do two things 1. remove the | from the first value and 2. if the checkbox is clicked again (i.e. deselected) remove the value from the field. Thanks so far!

Comment: I want to award you the answer as well as you really helped but only allows for one so my thanks friend!

Comment: Justin Erswell: Its ok yar..both my code and the one you accepted doing the right thing and in the same way ..anyway the final thing is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the value:

```
var linkids = $('#link_ids');
linkids.val(linkids.val() + this.value + "|"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't assign the ID of all the checkboxes to be the same it's really bad.

Second, assuming you want all the **checked** values separated by `|` then this code is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allInputs = $('input[name="_CKBXprod_link"]');
    allInputs.click(function() {
        $('#link_ids').val(allInputs.filter(":checked").map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join("|"));
    });
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/5ztFP/).